# Git tells me that the same file is being tracked and not tracked depending on the command that I use

Tags: git

When I use

> git status

I'm given a list of all of the files and directories that are not bing tracked

```
.idea/
src/main/java/edu/mason/insf/ann/annUML.uml
target/
```

However, when I try to checkout to another branch, but tells me:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:

        target/classes/...
```

and goes on to list a bunch of files in my target folder (that isn't being tracked).

When I try to remove the files anyway buy using either

```
git rm target/classes/...
```

or

```
git checkout target/classes
```

I'm given the following error

```
fatal: pathspec 'target/classes/...' did not match any files.
```

Git is essentially telling me that the same file is being tracked and not being tracked at the same time. It won't let me remove the file from my working tree and it also won't let me switch branches because the changes to this untracked file might be overwritten.

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: Your title suggests that git is telling you that some file is being tracked.  I don't see any error message in your question that indicates that; the error message states that `The following **untracked** working tree files would be overwritten.`  (Emphasis mine.)  You're welcome to remove them from your working tree, but since they're not tracked, you can't use `git rm` to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files are not tracked in the commit you currently have checked out, but *are* tracked in the commit you are *trying* to check out.  Git doesn't know if you have changes in your untracked copies that are important, and so it's refusing to clobber them with the copies in the commit.

`git rm` fails because it operates on tracked files that are in the index.  These files are untracked and therefore are not in the index, so it cannot operate on them.

To resolve this problem, remove the files using `rm` (*not* `git rm`) after confirming that you didn't make any changes in them that you want to keep.